# Elasticsearch Partial match or fuzzy match, boost partial results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Trying to query in Elasticsearch w/ the PHP client and give priority to partial words matches but still include fuzzy matches. If I remove the address.company match block, the query works as expected, but is broken with it present no matter how I seem to frame it. I am lost on the formatting to also include the fuzzy searches with a lower priority?

```
    $search_data = [
        "from"  => (int) $start, "size" => (int) $count,
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'filter' => [
                    ['term' => ['active' => 1]],
                    ['term' => ['type' => 2]],
                ],
                'must'   => [
                    'wildcard' => [
                        'address.company' => '*' . $search_query . '*'
                    ],
                    'match'    => [
                        'address.company' => [
                            'query'     => $search_query,
                            'operator'  => 'and',
                            'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: can you share your schema mappings

Answer (score 0):

While I am still new to ES as likely is apparent, this solution seems to get the data I'm after. I only mention that because there may be a more ideal way if someone views this in the future. Switching from must to should and wrapping the arrays a bit differently did the trick.

```
$search_data = [
    "from"  => (int) $start, "size" => (int) $count,
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'filter' => [
                ['term' => ['active' => 1]],
                ['term' => ['type' => 2]],
            ],
            'should'   => [
                [
                    'match' => ['address.company' => ['query'=>$search_query,'boost'=>10]],
                ],
                [
                    'match' =>
                     [
                         'address.company' =>
                             [
                                'query'     => $search_query,
                                'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                            ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'minimum_should_match'=>1,
        ],
    ],
];
```